# Can I exec and return a process with Go?

Tags: linux, go, process, exec

Can I execute a process and then pass it off to the user? I'm attempting to wrap around the SSH client. The program performs a set of actions to retrieve client authentication keys and then the idea was that it would execute the ssh client on the user's behalf and then "drop" them into the session. Is this possible with Go?

Comment: What exactly **is** *the ssh client*?

Comment: Processes cannot "be returned." Even a shell, like bash, can't do this. What _can_ be done (and what shells do), is set up I/O redirection of STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR between the terminal and the process. There's nothing stopping you from doing the same.

Comment: Are you trying to execute a command remotely over SSH? Look: https://zaiste.net/executing_commands_via_ssh_using_go/

Comment: If it's absolutely the very last thing your program does, you can [syscall.Exec](https://godoc.org/syscall#Exec) the ssh client, and it will replace your program; if the call is successful it won't return and your program won't exist any more, and from the point of view of the user, they're now running `ssh`.